# Algorithm using n processors in EREW machine for C[i]=A[B[i]]

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

Let A be an array of size n, and it contains only positive numbers.

Let B be an array of size n, and it contains number within the range [1,n].

Let C be an array of size n, and we are to do C[i]=A[B[i]] in O(log^2(n)) by using n processors in an EREW machine.

Notice that since B might contain duplicates, the reading conflict could happen.

My strategy was to enlarge A by the information of B so that we can do C[i]=A[B[i]+i] to solve the reading conflict issue. However, after hours of trying, I found it is impossible to enlarge A in such a way without reading conflict. I'm asking for some hints or suggestions here. Hence, a detailed solution is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you solve the problem when B is nondecreasing? Batcher's [bitonic mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) runs in time O(log^2 n) on an EREW.